# How to initialise char* with const char* not using const_cast?

Tags: c++

I have a lab with a task from "Programming Principles and Practice Using C++" which asks to write a function `char* findx(const char* s, const char* x);` that finds the first occurrence of the C-style string `x` in `s`.

But, I don't know how to do it without `const_cast`, so my solution is:

```cpp
char* findx(const char* s, const char* x)
{
    char* result{ const_cast<char*>( s ) };

    int s_size{ strlen(s) };
    int x_size{ strlen(x) };

    for(int i{ 0 }; i < s_size; ++i)
    {
        bool equal{ true };

        for(int j{ 0 }; j < x_size; ++j)
        {
            if(s[i + j] == x[j]) continue;
            equal = false;
            break;
        }

        if(equal) return ( result + i );
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Which is, for sure, not the one considered.

So, how can it be solved without `const_cast`?

Comment: the signature is broken and must be fixed. `const char* findx(const char* s, const char* x)`

Comment: You can't cast away constness without `const_cast`.  What is PPaP?  You should ask them why they want you to break const-correctness.

Comment: Why can't `result` be a `const char *`?

Comment: It needs to return a `const char*`. That is, you can set the pointer to a given value, but you can't change the thing it's pointing to. Else your function is little more than a `const_cast`.

Comment: "But I don't know how to do it without const_cast", you also cannot do it with `const_cast`, you would get it to compile, but it would be still wrong

Comment: I suppose the result should be `nullptr` or a pointer to the found occurrence in `s`. In that case there are two possibilities, either `s` should not be `const` or the return value should be `const`.

Comment: @NathanOliver PPaP is Programming Principles and Practice Using C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++17 the correct solution is to use `std::string_view` from the standard library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

int main()
{
    std::string_view text = "Joe waited for the train.";
    std::string_view search = "waited for";
    std::cout << text.find(search) << '\n';
}
```

```
4
```

"Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup is already quite old. I haven't read it myself, but I've heard good things about it. The exercise of Chapter 17 is:

> Write a function, `char* findx(const char* s, const char* x)`, that finds the first occurrence of the C-style string `x` in `s`.

This is unfortunately a very imprecise formulation, since it is not clear what the function should return. There are several options:

1. Like `std::string_view::find()` an integer with the position of `x` in `s` or `-1` if not found.
2. **A pointer to the beginning of `x` in `s` or `nullptr` if not found.**
3. A copy in a newly allocated memory space containing `x` or `nullptr` if not found.

The third option is would fit the specified return data type. However, this would be an extremely unrealistic implementation.

The previous exercise is:

> Write a function, `char* strdup(const char*)`, that copies a C-style string into memory it allocates on the free store. Do not use any standard library functions.

Very likely there was a typo here, and the question should actually be for `const char* findx(const char* s, const char* x)` returning the beginning of `x` in `s` or `nullptr` if `s` doesn't contains `x`. (Option 2)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

const char* findx(const char* s, const char* x)
{
    const std::size_t s_size = std::strlen(s);
    const std::size_t x_size = std::strlen(x);

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < s_size; ++i)
    {
        bool equal = true;

        for(std::size_t j = 0; j < x_size; ++j)
        {
            if(s[i + j] == x[j]) {
                continue;
            }

            equal = false;
            break;
        }

        if(equal)
        {
            return s + i;
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

Your implementation accomplishes this task:

```
int main()
{
    const char* text = "Joe waited for the train.";
    const char* search = "waited for";
    std::cout << findx(text, search) << '\n';
}
```

```
waited for the train.
```

Comment: It's on page 624, Exercises for Chapter 17.

Comment: @ProMike This is most certainly a mistake in the book. I have adapted the answer to the contents of the chapter.

Answer (score -5):

You don't need `const_cast`, but you definitely will need some way to cheat constness away. Input data is `const` and the return type should be non-const but pointing to a const source content ... this has to break constness as it is set in the requirements.

This could be done by unions without the compiler getting the idea:

```
char* findx(const char* s, const char* x) {
    union {
        const char* result;
              char* non_cost_result;
    } shared_storage;

    int s_size = strlen(s);
    int x_size = strlen(x);

    for(int i{ 0 }; i < s_size; ++i)
    {
        bool equal{ true };

        for(int j{ 0 }; j < x_size; ++j)
        {
            if(s[i + j] == x[j]) continue;
            equal = false;
            break;
        }

        shared_storage.result=&s[ i ];
        if(equal) return (shared_storage.non_cost_result);
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: `(char*)&result[ i ]` is preforming a `const_cast`, you are just hiding it with a c-style cast syntax.

Comment: i already said, the need to break constness is a requirement. that kind of "wash me, but don't make me wet".

but since you are right, i deleted my answer :-)

Comment: why do you think this is better than what OP has already?

Comment: because it doesnt cast

Comment: This kind of type punning through a `union` is **undefined behavior** in C++.

Comment: it is only undefined in case the inner structure of the unions's members differ. but here, we have the same init sequence as it is only the constness that differs.

Comment: At cppreference, I did not see any exception to the C++ active/inactive rule of union member variables merely because the inner structure of the union's members are the same.  The closest mention is "Many compilers implement, as a non-standard language extension, the ability to read inactive members of a union."  (My compiler does not have that non-standard language extension, and faults when accessing the inactive member.)

Comment: note that OP mentions that they have a solution but suspect that its not the one expected from them in the book. The question is not merely about getting it done somewhow without `const_cast`, but (reading between the lines) about what is the expected solution.